# Why import does not work after it is defined in __init__ file

Tags: python, importerror

I have the following project structure:

```
unit_tests/
  __init__.py  # 1
  bar/
    __init__.py  # 2
    test.py
  foo/
    __init__.py  # 3
    module2.py
    module1.py
```

__init__.py 1 and 2 are empty while 3 contains the following:

```
from .module1 import print1
from .module2 import print2
```

The reason I defined them is that this will allow bar/test.py to import print1 or print2 by just calling

```
from unit_tests.foo import print1
```

instead of

```
from unit_tests.foo.module1 import print1
```

So far so good. However, when I try to import print2 within module1:

```
from . import print2
```

I get the error: `ImportError: cannot import name print2`

Only `from .module2 import print2` works.

My question: Since I am in module1.py, which is in folder foo, why can't I use `from . import print2` to import print2? I find it strange because I am able to import print1 and print2 in bar/test.py without referencing module1 or module2.

Comment: Modules don't inherit the imports of their ancestors.  You need `from .module2 import print2`.

Comment: `from .module2 import print2
from .module1 import print1`

@TimRoberts When I switch the order by importing print2 first and print1 next in \_\_init\_\_.py, using `from . import print2` within module1.py actually works.

Answer (score 1):

You have to see that imports are executed just like any other statements.  For example, python will not try to import packages in a specific order.

So when importing `foo`, you first execute:
`from .module1 import print1` which import `module1.py`.
Then doing `from . import print2` in `module1.py` is incorrect since `from .module2 import print2` has not been executed yet in `foo/__init__.py`.  This is why exchanging the two lines of `foo/__init__.py` fixes the problem.

So either either you have to switch the two lines `foo/__init__.py` either you have to import `print2` as you did: `from .module2 import print2` to fix your problem.